# Typescript: computed property name in arguments from prior arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make a reusable `includes` function like so

```
type Primitive = string | boolean | number;

export const includesByAttribute = (
  attr: string,
  list: { [attr]: Primitive }[],
  val: { [attr]: Primitive },
) => {
  if (list.length > 0) return list.find((obj) => obj[attr] === val[attr]);
  return false;
};
```

hoping to define the second and third argument's type based on the first argument. Is there a way to enforce this?

I tried

```
export const includesByAttribute = (
  attr: string,
  list: { [attr: string]: Primitive }[],
  val: { [attr: string]: Primitive },
) => {
  if (list.length > 0) return list.find((obj) => obj[attr] === val[attr]);
  return false;
};
```

and when calling it, the 'value' argument is not considered, allowing the attribute of 'x' to exist in the second and third args

```
includesByAttribute('value', [{ x: 1 }], { x: 2 })) // compiles fine but doesn't achieve goal
```

Comment: Seems like you just want generics, possibly as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wEjagN). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The first argument of the call to `includesByAttribute` should be 'x'. The property 'value' does not exist on the object `{x: 1}`.  Try `includesByAttribute('x', [{ x: 1 }], { x: 2 }))`

Comment: @jcalz I love it, quite elegant. I added a comment in this [sandbox](https://shorturl.at/dlwQY) that it would be nice if the T type enforced the same exact type in second and third args. Is that possible? (used url shortener for link bc of [character limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376124/how-do-i-post-a-comment-with-a-really-long-url-which-will-never-fit-without-a-u)

Comment: @joas your code snippet also compiles and is how I intend to use the function when its working, my code snippet was a case of intended failure as a demonstration that my technique wasn't working (see comment next to my code block in question)

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7GLGN) what you're looking for, then? Let me know how to proceed (note that https://tsplay.dev is a shortener specifically for the ts playground so it's less iffy where you're sending someone)

Comment: @jcalz thank you, that is perfect, but could you possibly explain why that trick with the `& {}` works there to enforce second and third args same type?

Comment: Yes, if and when I actually write up an answer. I assume this means you're happy enough for me to do that? If so, I'll do so when I get a chance.   If not, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz yes, very happy, thanks very much for your time. I think an answer from you would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). That's the only way for you to have allowed types of multiple inputs depend on each other.  Here's one way to write it:

```
const includesByAttribute = <
    K extends PropertyKey,
    T extends Record<K, string | number | boolean>
>(
    attr: K,
    list: T[],
    val: NoInfer<T>,
) => {
    if (list.length > 0) return list.find((obj) => obj[attr] === val[attr]);
    return false;
};
```

Here the type parameter `K` corresponding to the `attr` input is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `PropertyKey`, meaning it should be keylike (it's `string | number | symbol`; you could make it just `string` if you want.)

And the type parameter `T` corresponding to the elements of the `list` input is constrained to `Record<K, string | number | boolean>` (using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) meaning that it should at least have a `string | number | boolean` property at the key `K` corresponding to `attr`. This doesn't require that *every* property of `T` be `Primitive`, just the one at key `K`.

You also want `val` to be of type `T`, but I've written `NoInfer<T>` to indicate that you don't want the compiler to *infer* `T` from `val`. If you left it as `T`, then the compiler would infer `T` from both `list` and `val` and it might allow extra keys to exist in `val` that don't exist in the element of `list`.  That is, you want the compiler to infer `T` from `list` *only*, and then just *check* `val` against it.  That way if you add extra keys to `val`, the compiler will complain.

So `NoInfer<T>` is meant to evaluate to `T`, but "block" or "shield" inference.  As of TypeScript 5.3 there is no built-in implementation of `NoInfer<T>`, and there was a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) asking for it.  Various user implementations of it exist in the discussion of that issue which work for various use cases.  One simple one is mentioned [in a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731): just [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with an empty object type `{}` to lower the inference priority:

```
type NoInfer<T> = T & {}
```

This works for your example. But the next version of TypeScript will very likely include [microsoft/TypeScript#56794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56794), which implements `NoInfer<T>` natively.  At which point you can discard the definition about and it will still behave.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
includesByAttribute('x', [{ x: 1 }], { x: 2 }); // okay
includesByAttribute('value', [{ value: 1, x: 1 }], { value: 2, x: 2 }); // okay

includesByAttribute('value', [{ x: 1 }], { x: 2 }); // error, x is not known
includesByAttribute('value', [{ value: 1, x: 1, z: 8 }], { value: 2, x: 2 }); // error, z missing
```

Looks good. The compiler accepts the first two calls and rejects the second two calls, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXimygDIoBvAXwFgAoegYziQGdgoBLJRgGwFcAJhFYAhEAEFgwdJwBG-YNCKZ6UdVADSUCAA8lSQaygAFdHEjpQmiCAA0ajST0GjUAEoRm6QZk12odlkkAHMoAB8oJH4AWzkMCKg5ODheCABDJFx6XAAKR3V06XQALi0HOg0oXk52MuwAbQBdCqqAN3TeMvhkNCw8CoBKQnwKAq4UKFya9gA6NNDgAAsofAAGYfQIYH50JGra4FmUbkFc3Lg5ACthgnxLq4aimSbCAiIO3ifipsGAbnGWx2eygKE6rAgALoVCh9Ho3D4QhE4ikMnkigguQA5J9+BAsQEGhQoLoygBGKBUFqUEllABMlP+UAA9MydOhzOgArouMYkHAOABrfkAdyQ8J4AmEYkkxXRSmxugJUCJtKgFKpAWJpKgDKoTNZUDggvSIAliOlKLlCgVOM6eOVqtxEHJ3PJlOpxOd9LdusZfxZbONpvNUuRsrRNsxdoE+MJXvtLvVvrJAQAXmUABwerVQb26316g1sjCc9NQGK1VjcEL0IA)

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your function signature, `attr` is a `string`, it can very well take the value of `value` or `x` without any issue.

For you to achieve this you need to somehow have `attr` have a string literal type. That way, if the `attr` has the value `x` it should have the type `'x'` and not `string`.

With that being said, your function should be generic. What about this?

```
export const includesByAttribute = <T extends string>(
  attr: T,
  list: { [k in typeof attr]: Primitive }[],
  val: { [k in typeof attr]: Primitive },
) => {
  if (list.length > 0) return list.find((obj) => obj[attr] === val[attr]);
  return false;
};
```

We make the function generic with `T`, a subtype of `string` and assign this type to `attr`. Then, in the next two arguments, we refer to `attr` with `[k in typeof attr]` as a way to define the object with the keys taken from `attr`'s type.

Finally, this way, your snippet at the end:

```
includesByAttribute('value', [{ x: 1 }], { x: 2 })) // compiles fine but doesn't achieve goal
```

Will not compile because `x` is not part of `{ value: Primitive }`.